# Zero dimensional varieties and the L-function $1/(1-p^{-n})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology, l-functions

I am interested in positive characteristic varieties which produce an L-function of the form $\frac{1}{1-χ} = \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty p^{-ns}$. It seems related to the positive characteristic variety being a singleton.

Consider the function
$$Z = \exp \left( \sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{N_n t^n}{n} \right)$$
whose definition is expounded on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_L-function). This formula gives the "derived" characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius endomorphism on $\mathbb{F}_p^\text{sep}$ for the right choice of $N_n$. It resembles the equation $\exp \circ \operatorname{Tr} \circ \log = \det$ for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

> I want to know about the relationship between $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \sum_{i=0}^∞ p^{-ns}$ and some kind of "zero dimensional with one prime" condition which ensures that the zeta function will be of this form.

Also, is there a relationship between the Riemann zeta function and the Artin L-functions of ℤ ⊗ ₚ as positive characteristic varieties, perhaps involving a product?

Is $1/(1-p^{-n})$ is maybe the Artin L-function of a simple positive characteristic variety?

Comment: The Hasse-Weil zeta function of a point is $1/(1-T)$.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Kimball can you link me to a discussion and maybe comment on how the zeta function of ℤ is related to the zeta functions of ℤ ⊗ ${}_{p}$

Comment: I fear there is quite a bit of confusion in this question. What do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{F}_p$? It is just $\mathbb{F}_p$. "Artin" $L$-functions appear in a global setting, e.g. for extension of number fields, so they are infinite products. The formula for your $Z$ appears within the convoluted proof of Artin formalism on that wikipedia page (it would also follow from the definition and the decomposition of the regular representation). Kimball's question above is the only meaningful question I can extract from it. Maybe you could clarify.

Comment: Why do you sum over $i$ and then use the variable $n$ in your sum term? Did you mean to sum over $n$?

Comment: @StevenClark yes, I intended i= n

Comment: @Kimball I think that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich for the ℤ ⊗ I wanted to be able to recover the Artin L function from the local L-functions through an infinite product, possibly in the way that ℤ  ⊗ ℤ⁄nℤ  ≅ Π ℤ ⊗ pⁿ or ℤ $\hookrightarrow$ ℤ̂.

Comment: Consider how the Riemann zeta function splits as a product in the way Euler found. Are the constituents of the product local L-functions over p and do we always have a decomposition of a global zeta function as a product of local L-functions? or maybe there is something about passing to ℚp first.

Comment: @Kimball   do you think that the precomposition with p⁻ˢ comes from ℤₚ ⭢ ₚ?